# Is it possible in python to train 2 SVMs on different columns of dataset and then use both SVMs to make the final prediction

Tags: machine-learning, svm, machine-learning-model

Suppose I have a dataset containing 20 columns. Now is there a way in python to train one SVM on the 1st 10 columns and the other SVM on the remaining 10 columns, and then combine the output of two SVMs to make the final prediction?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course!

It is a kind of ensemble model (a model that is combined of 2 or more models).

For example, random forest creates a lot of independent decision trees, with different samples and different columns in each of them.